# Google App Engine Local datastore console

Tags: java, google-app-engine, localdb

When I run my GWT app using Eclipse Plugin, I can access local ds viewer at  http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin but after converting to mvn project, I get a 
`HTTP ERROR: 404 NOT_FOUND
RequestURI=/_ah/admin
Powered by Jetty://`

I can access my app on same port, so it's indeed 8888.
Please give suggestions, thanks

**Update**: pom.xml

`

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <port>81</port>
                    <disableUpdateCheck>true</disableUpdateCheck>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>                                
                 <keepTempUploadDir>true</keepTempUploadDir>
                 <unpackVersion>${gaeVersion}</unpackVersion>
            <sdkDir>${settings.localRepository}/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.5.2/appengine-java-sdk-1.5.2</sdkDir>
                </configuration>                
            </plugin>
```

`

Comment: Your app works at `localhost:8888` but the admin console doesn't? That's crazy. I'm pretty sure the `maven-gae-plugin` hosts on `8080` by default.

Comment: Weird! Everything was OK until I converted to mvn, I thought converting to mvn proj would make dependency management easy but I could well be wrong.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with "dependency management"

Comment: I know I meant my reason for converting my project to mvn is because I want to enjoy easy dependency management and other advantages of mvn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by adding:

```
<server>com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher</server>
            <appEngineVersion>${gaeVersion}</appEngineVersion>
```

Comment: Where in the pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can set the port in the `pom.xml`:

```xml
  <plugin>
    <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version>
    ...
    <configuration>
      <port>8765</port>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>maven-gae-plugin-repo</id>
      <name>maven-gae-plugin repository</name>
      <url>http://maven-gae-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/repository/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```

Then check the console output:

```
27.04.2012 07:13:22 com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8765/
27.04.2012 07:13:22 com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8765/_ah/admin
```

Comment: Thanks @Moritz,  I have updated my Question with my pom, Please have a look, All this time, port is set to 81 but I have always accessed my app through `http://127.0.0.1:8888/LottoShop.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997` (when I click "launch default browser") from GWT Development Mode window. Thanks

Comment: You could try upgrading to the latest GAE plugin version 0.9.2.

Comment: Could you pls give me a link to 0.9.2 version, For a moment I though I had it but I have 0.9.0. Thanks

Comment: I just changed my post to include the plugin repository and the plugin version. The plugin will automatically get installed by Maven.

Comment: Yes, the plugin ver 0.9.2 was picked up, haven't noticed any significant changes though but I guess the new plugin will include bug fixes. thanks